# sscroll view not working in my code help me

Tags: android

This is my full code. It works fine, but problem is scroll view is not working and last 3 buttons do not show on scrolling. How to scroll and view last 3 buttons? How to see all of the screen using scroll view?

```
                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/scroller"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true" >
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/titlebar_background"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/test_button_image"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
 </ImageView>

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:text="San Diego Unified">
 </TextView>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2">
 </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>


 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="HEALTHY BODIES HEALTHY MINDS "
    android:textSize="12sp" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/twitter"
    android:text="Button Text" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout  

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

   android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
   <EditText  
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"  

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:background="#a8a8a8"
     android:paddingTop="15dp"
     android:hint="SEARCH SCHOOL BY NAME"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </EditText> 



  <!-- 

  <Button  
    android:id="@+id/Button01"  
    android:text="Press Here!"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">




 </Button> 

 -->


   <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:src="@drawable/title_search"
 />

 </RelativeLayout>  


 <RelativeLayout 

  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/test_button_image"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
 </ImageView>

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="14sp"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="false" 
  android:text="Our Mission is to nourish our students so they can be fueled and  
 ready   to learn because we believe Healthy Bodies Mean Healthy Minds .our farm to  
 school and garden to school programs promote healthy eating habits">
</TextView>

  </RelativeLayout>
 <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#000000"/>



   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright">


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/caption"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="SELECT A SCHOOL TO VIEW LUNCH OR BREAKFAST MENUS"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:divider="@color/background"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 <!--    
    <RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  -->

 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#a8a8a8"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"

      android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FARM TO SCHOOL" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TAKE A SURVEY" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SHARE THIS APP" 
    android:textSize="10dp"
    />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please check your code once by removing android:fillViewport="true". it should work

Comment: remove this line   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 0):

Set android:layout_marginBottom="100dip" in you last layout